# Nhibernate GetEntry with un-saved entity object

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Before I save an entity I want to check if its dirty.
So I have the entity object came back from the ajax. (with ID).
The object is not saved yet, and I want to get the entity entry with it:

```
// this will return null, I assume it is because the object it not persisted yet.
session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.GetEntry(entity);

// this will return what I want, but merge will save the object...
session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.GetEntry(session.Merge(entity));
```

Isnt this the entire idea behind dirty and un-dirty, is knowing them before the save action? 
How can I get the entry of the object without having the persisted object yet?

**Update**
To give a real life use case, Lets say that I have the method `NhiUtil.IsPropertyDirty` that inside do the `GetEntry` from above.

```
if(NhiUtil.IsPropertyDirty("Password",userEntityFromClient, session)){
    userEntityFromClient = Hush(userEntityFromClient.Password);
}
session.SaveOrUpdate(userEntityFromClient);
```

If I am forced inside `IsPropertyDirty` to merge/save `userEntityFromClient` in order to get `GetEntry` to work, I cant take business logic decisions before the actual save...
so the entire `IsPropertyDirty` is unusable...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why we do have the NHiberante. If you go through your question and read about ORM, you must find that exactly that's *why* these tools are here. That's what they do for us.

Other words, do the standard steps:

- 1) Get the object from the Client (upper layers/tiers) via deserialization
- *optional get the object from `session.Get(id)` and bind it, skip the Merge later*
- *optional do validation (business layer)*
- 2) Merge the object, `session.Merge()` and call the `SaveOrUpdate()`
- 3) Flush the session

That's pretty it. 1) If we firstly get-by-id and bind the object from the recieved data (JSON) we already do have an object in the **`ISession`**. And the `ISession` is the one doing for us the dirty checking

In case 2) that we have detached object, use the `session.Merge()` which will again do all for us inside of the `ISession`.

#### Flush, only the dirty

The essence is in the 3) Flushing. It will be converted into the Update/Insert statement only if the object is dirty. If it is the same (unchanged) ... no call to DB engine

Some interesting sources:

[Chapter 24. Best Practices](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#best-practices)

> #### In a three tiered architecture, consider using SaveOrUpdate().
>
> When using a distributed architecture, you could pass persistent objects loaded in the middle tier to and from the user interface tier. Use a new session to service each request. Use ISession.Update() or ISession.SaveOrUpdate() to update the persistent state of an object.

[9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)

> ... SaveOrUpdate() ...
>
> ...  using Merge(Object o). This method copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the session. In most applications with detached objects, you need both methods, SaveOrUpdate() and Merge().

And also interesting: Ayende - [The difference between Get, Load and querying by id](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id)

And the [12.1. Interceptors](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors), which allows to hook on some events, e.g.:

```
public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, 
    object id, 
    object[] currentState,
    object[] previousState, 
    string[] propertyNames,
    IType[] types)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I dont get one thing. isnt the entire idea behind dirty and non-dirty is to take decisions before the actual save has made... Please see my update... thanks

Comment: Do not get me wrong, but I am not sure, if you are not over-complicating this. The scenario I am typcally using. 1) Get the existing from persistence, 2) merge/deserialize into that object. All the time object is being referenced by `ISession`. 3) Business validation. 4) A) if any property/setting is now invalid... call rollback and send error set to client/upper layer 4) B) all validation correct. Explicit call to `session.Flush()`, transaction.Commit(). 5) NHibernate will call UPDATE or INSERT only if the amended object **is dirty**. I am pretty happy with these steps for some time ;)

Comment: in step 2, merging the objects wont save the dirty to the db? if yes, that is a problem... , can you edit your question and put these step into pseudo code? thanks

Comment: NO NO NO ;) do not worry, please do read this http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing. Until the **FLUSH**, is called *(via Flush mode or explictly if FlushMode is NONE)* DB Engine is NEVER called to do the write operation. *NOTE, be careful if you do not wrap your "write" operations with the Transaction and using the IDENTITY... then the flush is done because it must get the identity... and no roll back due to missing transacrtion!!!*

Comment: Thanks, I think I can accept this question, but can you please add pseudo code to your answer, it will help a lot to see these steps written down. you know... all the steps you wrote. thanks mate

Comment: Great if that helped ;) I would say, that for this question I can hardly add more. It would otherwise be a tutorial to "Write operations design" ;);) ... Good luck with NHibernate, amazing tool